# OpenSUSE или CentOS в качестве универсальной системы?

Tags: centos, opensuse

Сейчас на работе стоит Ubuntu, выполняющий роль в основном роль десктопа, через VNC при необходимости подключаюсь из дома чтоб что-то доделать, и от части сервера, так как на нем стоит svn-сервер и tomcat опять таки для синхронизации с домашним компьютером.
Без предыстории скажу, что хочу попробовать RPM-дистрибутивы. Сразу в голову пришло два варианта: OpenSUSE и CentOS.
Первый привлекает серьезным производителем, а второй полной совместимостью с RedHat, что означает наличие огромного количества квалифицированной документации.
Какой из этих дистрибутивов вызовет меньше проблем при настройке и работе?
Или я вообще не в ту сторону смотрю?

Answer (score 3):

Есть еще вариант - Fedora.

А вообще-то, попробуй сам и ту, и другую систему. Сам реши, что тебе больше нравится.
Я много чего попробовал и вернулся в результате к тому, с чего начал - Ubuntu. Но это мой путь и больше ничей.

Comment: <i>Но это мой путь и больше ничей</i><p>
Обеими руками за - нужно пробовать самому и делать выводы конкретно для себя. Кому-то удобнее будет в одной системе, кому-то - в другой.

Answer (score 1):

у меня когда-то тоже стоял такой вопрос: что выбрать? из всех дистров я выбрал openSuse,как и почему я выбрал - я сидя на винде,начал гуглит,и искал я не холливары,а форумы,смотрел на количество тем и время отклика на вновь созданные темы,также смотрел уровень вопросов,например на ubunt-о подобных дистров,слишком много вопросов,мягко скажем "блондинистых" и тупых,которые можно решить не задавая вопроса а просто найти в документации.поэтому я решил,что хоть и поддержка большая,но мой вопрос может затеряться,среди других вопросов...к чему это я?я веду это к тому,что сейчас начнется холливар и будут советовать разное,но принимать решение будешь ты,исходя из внутренних убеждений,знаний и возможностей.чтобы решить этот вопрос,следует просмотреть в сети форумы на на наличие тех тем,которые для тебя актуальны,будь то настройка свистелок-перделок,то посмотри где больше информации и где больше проблем без ответов,надеюсь мой поток сознания наведет на правильный для тебя поиск дистра,решать тебе.

Answer (score 1):

По своему личному опыту скажу: администрировать openSuse сложнее, чем Ubuntu. Выражается это в настройках драйверов для принтеров и обновлении системы на более новую версию(например с 11.2 на 11.3 могут возникнуть проблемы с Х). При установке пакетов через графический интерфейс не разрешаются все зависимости(если в консоли через zypper то разрешаются). С другой стороны YaST достаточно удобен и прост в понимании. Так что для продвинутого пользователя проблем не возникнет. Думаю здесь все зависит от твоих личных предпочтений

Comment: 1. Проблем с Yast'ом и зависимостями не наблюдал. Зато в Ubuntu зависимости ломаются на ура.<p>
2. Апгрейдить систему вообще опасно, если это не gentoo/*bsd. Убунту вроде спокойно перетягивается, но нюансы все равно есть. В любом случае, clean install с сохранением домашнего каталога - лучшее решение проблем.<p>
3. YaST - мегаутилита! Очень удобно. Только ради него стоит ставить OpenSuSe.<p>
4. По впечатлениям 11.4 сырее, чем 11.3. Правда, на десктопе у сестры 11.4 работает лучше, чем 11.<p>
5. С принтерами HP вообще никаких проблем не видел. Win-принтеры не рассматриваем как класс.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще **CentOS** чаще используют на серверах, получить в сообществе помощь по поводу десктопного ПО будет сложнее (дольше), чем в **OpenSUSE**. А вот по поводу серверной документации вы правильно подметили.

А вообще люди редко уходят с *deb*-дистрибутивов на *rpm*-based. Скорее наоборот.
Я б на вашем месте лучше дома поигрался со всеми этими штуками, потому что слишом велик шанс, что вы вернетесь назад.

Answer (score 1):

обе системы хороши в качестве серверов. и обе возможны в качестве десктопов.
но opensuse всё равно лучше, как десктоп.

Comment: Наверное, «но opensuse всё равно **лучше**, как десктоп»?

Comment: спасибо, исправил :)

Answer (score 1):

Я лично за OpenSUSE. CentOS уж больно какой-то серверный. К тому же, мне компания Red Hat никогда не нравилась :-)

Answer (score 1):

А я отдам голос против openSUSE, потому что она очень сырая и жутко нестабильная. Я установил себе её в качестве эксперимента после нескольких лет работы под Mandriva и был крайне недоволен. Вернулся назад в итоге.

Comment: В случае 11.4 - согласен, релиз вышел сыроватой.

Comment: Я был очень огорчён увиденным. Это при том, что первые впечатления были скорее положительными, чем отрицательными..

Comment: А кто мешает поставить 11.3? Благо секьюрити апдейты и под нее тоже выходят. Я склонен думать, что в ситуации виновата схема выпуска ПО, привязанная к конкретным релиз-датам.
К тому же на десктопах 11.4 показала себя неплохо: у сестры (работает лучше, чем 11.3, конфиг - A64, мать на nForce4, видео Radeon ~HD5670) и у бухгалтера (правда, пришлось подшаманить с драйвером видеокарты - есть известная проблема с интегрированными GeForce 7-й серии)

Comment: Известная проблема? Ни разу не слышал :) Правда, у меня внешняя 7й серии была. Но по моему опыту ATI (который был с этими картами не далее чем два года назад) - это кошмар.. вечные мучения и напильник, напильник, напильник.. чтож, рад слышать, что проблемы эти в прошлом..

Comment: <i>вечные мучения и напильник, напильник, напильник</i><p>
Пришлось только через xrandr сделать частоту развертки 85Гц. С другой стороны, семерка тоже не хотела давать 85Гц на монитор и в семерке эта проблема по-простому не решалась. Так что проблема не в линуксе, а до некоторой степени в железе.<p>
<i>Известная проблема? Ни разу не слышал</i><p>
<a href=http://lists.suse.com/opensuse-bugs/2011-03/msg00622.html>[Bug 669783] nouveau [GeForce 7025 / nForce 630a] Hard distortion due to broken acceleration</a>

Comment: Ааа... nouveau..  у меня на ноуте он просто не работает, а выдаёт на экране такие шикарные психоделические картины из категории фрактального безумия в чёрнобелой гамме :) Используйте нормальный драйвер, а не занимайтесь Open-Paranoia :)

Comment: Пришлось ставить проприетарщину :-) Хотя те же опенсурсные драйвера radeon/radeonhd вполне функциональны.

Answer (score 0):

На вкус и цвет...
Лично мне нравится rolling-release дистрибутивы такие как gentoo, archlinux